# How do I calculate PDF (probability density function) in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, probability-density

I have the following code below that prints the PDF graph for a particular mean and standard deviation.

[image]

Now I need to find the actual probability, of a particular value. So for example if my mean is 0, and my value is 0, my probability is 1. This is usually done by calculating the area under the curve. Similar to this:

[http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~mbognar/applets/normal.html](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/%7Embognar/applets/normal.html)

I am not sure how to approach this problem

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
def normal(power, mean, std, val):
    a = 1/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*std)
    diff = np.abs(np.power(val-mean, power))
    b = np.exp(-(diff)/(2*std*std))
    return a*b

pdf_array = []
array = np.arange(-2,2,0.1)
print array
for i in array:
    print i
    pdf = normal(2, 0, 0.1, i)
    print pdf
    pdf_array.append(pdf)

plt.plot(array, pdf_array)
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.axis([-2, 2, 0, 5])
plt.show()

print
```

Answer (score 16):

Unless you have a reason to implement this yourself. All these functions are available in [scipy.stats.norm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html)

I think you asking for the **cdf**, then use this code:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
print(norm.cdf(x, mean, std))
```

Comment: I am using C++. Unless you are telling me there is an eigen function

Comment: OP: "This is usually done by calculating the area under the curve." That would be the CDF, not the PDF as this answer suggests.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to write it from scratch:

```
class PDF():
    def __init__(self,mu=0, sigma=1):
        self.mean = mu
        self.stdev = sigma
        self.data = []

    def calculate_mean(self):
        self.mean = sum(self.data) // len(self.data)
        return self.mean

    def calculate_stdev(self,sample=True):
        if sample:
            n = len(self.data)-1
        else:
            n = len(self.data)
        mean = self.mean
        sigma = 0
        for el in self.data:
            sigma += (el - mean)**2
        sigma = math.sqrt(sigma / n)
        self.stdev = sigma
        return self.stdev

    def pdf(self, x):
        return (1.0 / (self.stdev * math.sqrt(2*math.pi))) * math.exp(-0.5*((x - self.mean) / self.stdev) ** 2)
```

Comment: Actually, density at a point is **0**, you need the area of an interval to get the pdf.
What you can do is take an _epsilon_ value, suppose **1e-6**, and integrate over the area between **x & x+e** to calculate the pdf at a point.
It won't be accurate, but close. 
[integral-calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) -> this site could help you reformulate your pdf equation.

Comment: you can add this equation on the site: _1/(sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * exp(-(x-mu)^2/(2*sigma^2))_ and then put in the limits say 2 and 2.0000001, it will give you the equations.

Answer (score 4):

The area under a curve `y = f(x)` from `x = a` to `x = b` is the same as the integral of `f(x)dx` from `x = a` to `x = b`. [Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) has a quick easy way to do integrals. And just so you understand, the probability of finding a single point in that area cannot be one because the idea is that the total area under the curve is one (unless MAYBE it's a delta function). So you should get `0 ≤ probability of value < 1` for any particular value of interest. There may be different ways of doing it, but a conventional way is to assign confidence intervals along the x-axis [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixhsn.jpg). I would read up on Gaussian curves and normalization before continuing to code it.